# What are the best open-source free journals for ESL/EFL?

Tags: discussion, resource-request

For academics who don't have access to subscription-based online journals, what are some of the best open-source (free) journals related to English language teaching and learning? Peer-reviewed journals would be preferred.

[EDIT] I am looking for **good quality** journals that are free, rather than simply a list of free resources. So if someone has experience with a specific journal and can attest to its quality, that would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have seen the following journals?

1. http://www.tesl-ej.org/wordpress/ -  The Electronic Journal for English as a Second Language is a peer-reviewed, freely available journal which publishes a mix of research papers and conceptual overviews by established and emergent authors.
2. https://escholarship.org/uc/uccllt_l2/aimsAndScope - supported and hosted by the University of California, Berkeley
3. https://citejournal.org - Contemporary Issues in Technology and Teacher Education (CITE Journal) is an open-access, peer-reviewed publication of the Society for Information Technology and Teacher Education (SITE)

Comment: They look excellent, thank you so much